# Is it possible to use Mockito to completely stop a method from running?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm unit testing a method that has a lot of logic in it. It goes something like this:

```
public void doSomething(int number){

    //... complex logic

    if (number % 2 == 0)
       someInstanceObject.setOdd(false);
    else
       someInstanceObject.setOdd(true); 

    //... more complex logic and database connections
}
```

Is it possible for Mockito to just end the method execution after that if-else statement? The reason why I want to do this is because I want to test both conditions using `Mockito.verify()`. I want it to stop right away because after the if-else blocks, there would be a lot of stuff that needs mocking like database connections.

Believe me, if I can just refactor this, put the if-else statement in some other utility class and expose it as public, I would. But it turns out that I can't refactor the code anymore.

Comment: Can you add code to the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to stop after the if using Mockito. How would you say to mockito at which point you want to stop?

But you can try a dirty solution - mock some method call that succeedes the if to throw an exception and then in your test method just catch it. It will stop method execution and you don't have to mock all the DB stuff.

Comment: I think this would be a dirty solution but I guess it would be better than mocking the rest. :/

Answer (score 0):

No, I can't imagine that it is possible for Mockito to return at an earlier point from a method. Mockito would need to pop values from the stack and change the control flow. How would you specify in the code which part you want execute?

What you could do is mocking the method so that it executes the first statements. However, you would be testing against mocked code in that case. Furthermore, you would introduce a code clone (which may run out of sync with the original code).

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the second part to another method, probably with package visibility and then mock that method with `doNothing()`.

However, I believe that once you are at this point, you should reconsider the design.

Comment: Yeah I can't change the code just for a better unit test. Business rules.